# Use facebook login SDK with angular 5 web site

Tags: facebook, angular5, facebook-login

I have a site written with angular 5, I want to add option to login with facebook.
I tried to work with angular5-social-login, but I cannot understand how to pass the user and password?
and how to check if the user is already logged in?
how to put facebook login button in the html?
and how do I add facebook login product (in the facebook developers) with angular?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution and I used angularx-social-login much more easier.